# Make textbox required if a certain value is selected in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html

On a form, I have the following required drop down box:

```
<select id="SelectBox" name="SelectBox" required>
<option value="">Please Select ...</option>
<option value="val1">val1</option>
<option value="val2">val2</option>
<option value="val3">val3</option>
<option value="val4">val4</option>
</select>
```

I also have the following textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox">
```

I am trying to make the textbox required only if val4 is selected from the dropdown box using the required attribute (red border around textbox). I have done this with a radio button group, but need to do the same with this dropdown box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Adding `required` attribute does not automatically require text input at element. Should text input also be required at `#textbox` element?

Comment: @guest271314 `#textbox` would be use in jQuery which isn't tagged.

Comment: @NewToJS _"`#textbox` would be use in jQuery which isn't tagged."_ ? How does `#textbox` selector relate to jQuery?

Comment: @guest271314 well since the input `ID` is `textbox` and jQuery uses `#` to define `ID`'s and `.` to define a `class`, using `#textbox` would relate to using a jQuery selector. How else would you use `#textbox` in pure javascript?

Comment: @NewToJS _"using `#textbox` would relate to using a jQuery selector."_ That is not an entirely exclusive or correct assumption. _"How else would you use `#textbox` in pure javascript?"_ At `javascript` without using jQuery: `document.querySelector("#textbox")`; at `css` : `#textbox{property:value}`

Comment: @NewToJS Do you now gather how `#textbox` selector is not exclusively related to jQuery?

Comment: @guest271314 Ah yes, `querySelector()` my apologies! We all make mistakes / forget.

Answer (score 1):

This should work to make text input attribute `required` and add some **red border** if you select the **val4** option from the select box only.

```
 var select = document.getElementById("SelectBox");
 var textBoxElement = document.getElementById("textbox");

 select.onchange = function(){

    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selectedString == 'val4'){

       textBoxElement.required = true;
       textBoxElement.style.border="1px solid red";

    }else{

       textBoxElement.required = false;
       textBoxElement.style.border="";
    }   
}
```

See working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nwk1tkb7/5/

Comment: What if I choose val2  after selecting val4.

Comment: strange...I see that the jfiddle works, but when I apply to my page, it is not working. Could there be a reason? The page I am using is in a WordPress site, but I dont think that matters because other JS functions are working. Then, I also copied and pasted your html and JS in a regular html page and it still did not work. And I did add the opening and closing script tags.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I'd suggest is the following:

```
// use of a named function, to be called via Elememt.addEventListener:
function elementRequiredIf(event) {

  // 'this' will be the <select> element in this example, however
  // the 'this' is automatically passed from Element.addEventListener
  // (as is the 'event' object, though we don't use that here):
  var changed = this,

  // here we find the conditionally-required element, using
  // the id of the element stored in the custom data-* attribute
  // of the <select> element, here we retrieve that attribute-
  // value from the dataset object, stored as a property of the
  // Element:
    requiredElement = document.getElementById(changed.dataset.required_elem_id),

  // as above, we use the same approach to retrieve the
  // value that makes the other element required:
    ifRequiredValueIs = changed.dataset.required_if_value;

  // here we set the required property of the element to
  // true (if the <select> value is equal to the required
  // value, or false if they are unequal:
  requiredElement.required = changed.value === ifRequiredValueIs;
}

// here we find the <select> element via its id,
// and bind an event-listener for the 'change' event,
// which, upon a change event being fired, calls the
// named function (note the deliberate, required, lack
// of parentheses following the function name):
document.getElementById('SelectBox').addEventListener('change', elementRequiredIf);
```

```js
function elementRequiredIf() {
  var changed = this,
    requiredElement = document.getElementById(changed.dataset.required_elem_id),
    ifRequiredValueIs = changed.dataset.required_if_value;
  requiredElement.required = changed.value === ifRequiredValueIs;
}

document.getElementById('SelectBox').addEventListener('change', elementRequiredIf);
```

```css
input:required {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #f00;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="SelectBox" name="SelectBox" data-required_elem_id="textbox" data-required_if_value="val4" required>
    <option value="">Please Select ...</option>
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
    <option value="val3">val3</option>
    <option value="val4">val4</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o9z2v7hx/).

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: Setting `required` attribute does not automatically require text input at element. The `<form>` can still be submitted without any text value at the element; e.g., an empty string as value. OP has not clarified if actual text input at the element is required by user.

Comment: @guest271314: Setting `required` certainly [prevents Chrome from submitting the form](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1VXCo.png) without an entry, though admittedly I've not tested cross-browser. Also it's worth noting that I'm setting the `required` *property*, rather than the *attribute* (which doesn't *always* reflect the updated property-value).

Comment: At jsfiddle, try selecting `val4`, focus at `#textbox` element, press space key, press `Submit`

Comment: Yes, it makes the *element* required, if the OP wants to know how to determine the presence of a value then that's a separate topic that is entirely absent from the question as asked. I'm happy to add the details, if required, but it is, as yet, unasked for.